# Why am I unable to download a zip file with selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to use selenium in order to try to download a testfile from a html webpage. Here is the complete html page I have been using as test object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testpage</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
    Example Download link: 
        <a href="testzip.zip">Download this testzip</a> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

which I put in the current working directory, along with some example `zip` file renamed to `testzip.zip`.

My selenium code looks as follows:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/tmp")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False )
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True )                                       profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/zip")
profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/zip")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get('file:///home/path/to/html/testweb.html')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Download this testzip")]').click()
```

However, if I run the test (with `nosetest` for example), a browser is being opened, but after that nothing happens. No error message and no download, it just seems to 'hang'.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It may be because of the file url. Host the site using a normal http server and then test. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and test `http://localhost:8000/testweb.html`

Comment: Yes thanks, now it works. But unfortunately I am no closer to solve the actual problem. Because for a different non-public webpage I have a similar download link and here it does not work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up a real web server. You just have a html page but not a server to serve static files. You need to at least setup a server first.

But if your question is just related to download files, you can just use some international web site to test. It will work.

Comment: I have, in fact, a problem with a different webpage and wanted to make sure my selenium code works. It works in this case and maybe with many other pages, but not with the page I am actually about to test (including the generated data in the zip file). The download does not start...

Comment: @Alex First, make sure the site you want to test is a real & complete one. Second, in your html page, the path of file should like `/testzip.zip` but not something without `/`. The code you use to download has no problem.

Comment: I just got a popup on the browser with the real webpage asking me where to download the file. I thought I have deactivated this popup...

Comment: @Alex Without a real example, I can't tell more. The example given in your question is absolutely not a *website* but just a *html page*.

Comment: Yes I understand you. I have to find some other way to solve this problem myself. No idea how to do that, but I HAVE TO. Thanks anyway...